# Does Odata allow a duplicate property in an entity?

Tags: properties, odata, entity, specifications

I am dealing with an OData API that has a duplicate property in an entity. Does the OData specification allow that? I am asking because I am wondering whether I should make the code that consumes the API so robust as to be able to deal with the duplicate property? Or should I rather file a bug report for the API owner and have that code throw an error until the API is fixed?

I have checked the Odata documentation at https://www.odata.org/documentation/ but couldn't find anything regarding this question there.

The response I get from that API looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="..." xmlns="..." xmlns:m="..." xmlns:d="...">
  <id>...</id>
  ...
  <entry m.etag="...">
    <id>...</id>
    ...
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:ObjectID>...</d:ObjectID>
        ...
        <d:ProductID>...</d:ProductID>
        ...
        <d:ProductID>...</d:ProductID>
        ...
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  ...
</feed>
```

The `ProductID` property is provided twice by the API. I cannot really imagine that this is allowed in any API specification because as a consumer I would not know which instance of the two properties holds the "true" value.

Comment: What is the URL associated with the namespace `xmlns:d`?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni, that is not relevant to my question: I don't care about this particular OData API. My question is, should my code be able to deal with it (because it's allowed) or should I throw an error?